# How do I pass a variable from one function to another function?

Tags: excel, vba, function, byref

I am trying to pass a variable from one function to another function.

My first thought is to use the ByRef declaration which I hear will pass arguments by reference in Visual Basic. I am unclear, however, on how to use it. Right now I have the following code.

```
            Function number(x As Double) As Double

                Dim z As Double
                z = 10.5
                number = x

            End Function

            Function triple(ByRef z As Double) As Double

                z = z * 3
                triple = z

            End Function
```

Lets say `A1=2.5`. If I say `B1=number(A1)` then the answer is 2.5 which I expected it to be. I then say `B2=triple(B1)` but then the answer is 7.5 instead of 31.5. I am not sure why it's taking the value of `A1` instead of taking the value of the variable `z` from the function `number`.

Here's a screenshot of the worksheet

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using them from Excel UI as User Defined Function or in a VBA code?

Comment: @user3598756 this is for VBA code

Comment: so what are `A1`, `B1` and `B2`? show a snippet of your VBA code that uses those functions

Comment: @user3598756 see my answer below which contains the snippet. My VBA code is what you see above in the original post.

Comment: so your _real_ answer was "Yes, I'm using them from Excel UI as User Defined Function"

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z inside the number function is gone by the time the function returns. The triple function just tipples the number passed, 2.5 times 3 which is what you are seeing. The tipple function has no idea of z.
One way to share variables is to declare them outside of the functions.
Dim z as double outside the function.
But then if you pass z as the value of b1 which is 2.5 then you will get the same 7.5 just call triple, don't pass the value of b1

Dim z As Double

```
    Function tripple(x As Double)
        ' Use the value calculated from first function
        tripple = z * 3

    End Function
    Function number(x As Double)

        ' Set the global variable
        ' May be some calculations are done and z is set
        z = 10.5

        'Return x as in original code
        number = x
    End Function
```

Comment: What if you're in a situation where you need to recall a variable calculated from the input of the first function so that you may use it in the second function? How would `z` be used then?

Comment: you could try defining the variable as a global. Try with Public z As Double outside the functions. This variable should be available to all functions in the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I'm totally confused by what you are trying to do.  My initial thought would be to do something like this, which is similar to what @dgorti suggested, but reverting to the input value of the function if `z` has never been declared.

VBA, unfortunately, does not support nullable Doubles, to the best of my knowledge, nor does it allow initialization of global variables.  Either of these capabilities might preclude the need for the `zDeclared` variable below:

```
Option Explicit

Public z As Double
Public zDeclared As Boolean

Function number(x As Double) As Double
    z = 10.5
    zDeclared = True
    number = x
End Function

Function triple(x As Double) As Double

  If zDeclared Then
    triple = z * 3
  Else
    triple = x * 3
  End If

End Function
```

**CAVEAT:**  This may not do what you expect.  For example, if you call `number` and then call `triple`, the variable `z` will have been initialized.  If you delete the function that calls `number`, you might expect `triple` to revert to the input value -- but it won't.  What's done is done at this point.

And, in the way of explanation, the difference between the default `ByVal` in a parameter versus the optional `ByRef` is that `ByVal` creates a new instance of the parameter value, whereas `ByRef` uses the existing variable and therefore retains any changes to it.  Maybe you understood that already, but I thought it worth clarifying.

```
Sub IncrementByVal(ByVal inp As Integer)
  inp = inp + 1
End Sub

Sub IncrementByRef(ByRef inp As Integer)
  inp = inp + 1
End Sub

Sub Test()
  Dim X As Integer
  X = 1
  IncrementByVal X  ' x is still 1  - the increment was for a locally scoped variable only
  IncrementByRef X  ' x is now 2
End Sub
```